# How to use mouseover in react

Tags: html, css, reactjs, html-lists

> I am new to react.js and i am stuck at a point that where i need to set
>   the moverover on div and if the mouse is over on that div then call the id of
>   other div so that the content within that id can be displayed. any type of help will always be appreciated

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#mouse-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave events.

```
    <div
      onMouseEnter={this.onMouseEnter.bind(this)}
      onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave.bind(this)}
      style={{ border: "1px solid red", width: "50%", height: "250px" }}
    />
    <div>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/13l5l4x04l

Comment: Thanks for your perfect answer @jsdeveloper